# Replace render :update for rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

It seems that the method render :update is not supported anymore in Rails 3.1, now I'm checking what the best way is to change this code :

```
def create
  @address = @current_user.addresses.build(params[:address])
  @address.save!
  respond_to do |accepts|
    accepts.html {
      flash[:notice] = t(:"notices.address.created")
      redirect_to :back
    }
    accepts.js {
      flash[:notice] = t(:"notices.address.created")
      render :update do |page|
        page.redirect_to(:back)
      end
    }
  end
end
```

I just need to do a redirect :back when the action is succesful, but for the moment he just try to render the update partial.

Comment: In the meanwhile I fixed it with making a back.js.erb file that contains window.location = "<%=escape_javascript(request.env['HTTP_REFERER']) %>"; and in my controller I do then render :back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render :js => "window.location = #{escape_javascript(request.env['HTTP_REFERER'])}"
```